# How to burn multiple .mp4 files to a DVD

Tags: video, dvd-burning

I have several .mp4 files ranging from say 500 MB to 1.5 GB.

After doing some reading, I learned that these .mp4 files will take even more space on DVD (playable on DVD-player), if I don't want to compromise on quality. **How can I know in advance how much each of these files would take on DVD so that I can plan accordingly (like what files should be grouped up etc)?**

Also, I was playing around with DVD Flick (but I heard it has audio/video sync issues), and I could not determine proper bitrate. I felt odd selecting Target Bitrate as Auto-fit, because that would mean quality loss. **How should I select target bitrate?**

Any DVD burner (from mp4) (freeware) you recommend?

Comment: Check your DVD player to see if it can play video files (eg look in the manual for “DivX”, “MP4”, etc.) If it can, then Michael is correct and it would be easier to just burn the video files to a disc instead of converting them (assuming that you don’t need it to be playable on all DVD players).

Comment: I can not assume that DVD player can play MP4.

Comment: Okay then if you must convert to MPEG2, you should consider running an analysis pass on the videos to collect bitrate distribution so that you can get the best possible quality across the video when you run the encoding pass. If you have several videos from 500-1,536MB (ie, the disc is almost full with *compressed videos*, then you *will not* be able to fit them on a single DVD5 in MPEG2 format, so you’ll **have** to accept quality loss during the conversion. There are plenty of tools that can analyse a video to give you extensive information like bitrates, which you can then use as the input.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an image with all the files you want with [imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/), then you will see how big it is and you can burn it on DVD. Normally there should be no difference between the normal file size and the file size on DVD, due most DVD players are able to play most media types without any conversion.

Comment: Add: "How should I select target bitrate?" Why don't you use the bitrate of your mp4 files?

Comment: [DVD Flick](http://www.dvdflick.net/index.php) is a DVD authoring program, they’re probably asking about converting the videos to DVD format (MPEG2), not simply burning some video files to a DVD-ROM. And only DVD players that specifically say that they support video files can play them (look for ones that say DivX, WMV, and MP4).